Sveltekit with Prisma and multpile Clients
I have the following problem with a Sveltekit project in which I need two different schemas.
My schemas are located in:

prisma\data\data.prisma
prisma\web\web.prisma

If I use the following code as generator:
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
    output = "../../node_modules/@prisma-web/client"
}

Are the client folders created correctly in node_modules and I can use both in a lib/prisma.js as follows:
import { PrismaClient as WebClient } from '@prisma-web/client'
export const web = new WebClient()

However, the two clients are always deleted as soon as I install a new package, so that I always have to recreate the clients with generate, which is unfortunately really annoying.
If I change the generators in the schema as follows:
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
    output = "./client"
}

Are they created in the respective prisma folder, for example: prisma\web\client
After an npm generate I get this message without error:
Start using Prisma Client in Node.js (See: https://pris.ly/d/client)
import { PrismaClient } from './prisma/web/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

However, if I then change my lib/prisma.js to this:
import { PrismaClient as WebClient } from './prisma/web/client'
export const web = new WebClient()

I get the error:

[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/lib/prisma.js: failed to
import "./prisma/web/client" |- ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Can anyone help me here?

When you write "the two clients are always deleted as soon as I install a new package", do you mean that when you add a new dependency to the project, the generated clients are deleted? Why would this happen?

Exactly, if i run npm install the Folders /node_modules/@prisma-web and @prisma-data stay, but the client folder inside gets deleted. Why? I dont know, thats the reason why I am here :)
